# MySQL запрос

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как при помощи SQL запроса(можно использовать mysql функции в php) сделать UPDATE полей следующим образом:
есть у нас столбец gallery(TEXT), в нем текст в следующем формате:
имя фото 1, имя фото 2, ..., имя фото n
А нужно чтобы было следующим образом:
["имя фото 1","имя фото 2",...,"имя фото n"]
Ну формат json в общем...
Можно использовать код php или несколько SQL запросов, но я вообще не могу справиться с этой задачей.

Comment: а в чем проблема? Вы не знаете, как делать конкатенацию строк чтобы из строки 'one two three' получить  '["one", "two", "three"]'? По-моему, элементарно

Comment: @DreamChild, смотрите тут такая проблема, что строка сейчас:
one, two, three, ну а надо ["one","two","three"]

Comment: ну и что же?

Comment: можете показать листинг примерный для one, two, three?

Comment: > в нем текст в следующем формате: имя фото 1, имя фото 2, ..., имя фото n

Это одно значение в ячейке? Или в каждой ячейке "имя фото 1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче, если в разных ячейках, то так:

```
select concat('[',group_concat('"',gallery,'"'),']') from t;
```

А если в одной, то эдак:

```
select concat('["', replace(gallery,',','","'),'"]') from t;
```

Comment: огромнейшее вам спасибо - как выйду в плюс по рейтингу - вас награжу

Comment: Чтобы выйти в плюс по рейтингу, не нужно задавать минусовые вопросы. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Семён, вы не обижайтесь, но какой вам к черту листинг? Вы своей головой лучше подумайте - для вашего программистского развития это будет куда полезнее. Не нужно использовать этот ресурс как место, где за вас сделают вашу домашнюю работу. Здесь вам могут помочь, но желающих работать за вас вряд ли найдется.

Конкретно по сабжу - если все делается на сервере приложения, то в php это элементарно, гуглите про разбиение строки на подстроки (или массив, не знаю, как там в php) и про конкатенацию.  Если нужно все делать на сервере БД, то можете распарсить строку регулярным выражением. Это будет посложнее. Возможно, с регулярокой возникнут проблемы (вообще не в курсе, есть ли их поддержка в MySQL, в таком случае можете сделать "грязный" трюк - вытащите данные SQL-запросом и с помощью php разбейте строку на составляющие ("one", "two" и "three"), а потом проведите конкатенацию с учетом необходимых скобочек, запятых и тд. После этого сделаете update таблицы получившимися дванными. Выглядит сложнее,чем есть на самом деле.

З.Ы. Это на случай, если вся ваша информация хранится в одной ячейке. Если в разных, то все еще проще, и может быть выполнено без регулярных выражений на сервере БД

З.З.Ы. Если все же в одной ячейке, то это говорит про плохую нормализацию и несоблюдение правил [1НФ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0), и в первую очередь стоит подумать именно об этом

Answer (score 0):

```
//Это у нас записано в БД
//a:3:{i:0;s:9:"img_1.jpg";i:1;s:9:"img_2.png";i:2;s:9:"img_3.bmp";}
$s = serialize(array('img_1.jpg', 'img_2.png', 'img_3.bmp'));

echo $s;

//Функция для добавления изображения
function addImage()
{
    //Ув. ТС потренеруйте мозг в этой функции
}

//функция для удаления изображения
function deleteImage($img, $s)
{
    $u = unserialize($s);

    if(($key = array_search($img, $u)) !== false)
    {
        unset($u[$key]);
    }

    return $u;
}

//функция для изменения изображения
function updateImage($img, $new_img, $s)
{
    $u = unserialize($s);

    if(($key = array_search($img, $u)) !== false)
    {
        $u[$key] = $new_img;
    }

    return $u;
}

//Это мы запишим после удаления изображения
//a:2:{i:1;s:9:"img_2.png";i:2;s:9:"img_3.bmp";}
echo serialize(deleteImage('img_1.jpg', $s));

//Это мы запишим в БД после изменения изображения
//a:3:{i:0;s:12:"img_155.jpeg";i:1;s:9:"img_2.png";i:2;s:9:"img_3.bmp";}
echo serialize(updateImage('img_1.jpg', 'img_155.jpeg', $s));
```

Прелесть в том что мы всегда будем иметь на выходе массив изображений! Почитайте про **сериализацию** данных!